# How to compile kivy and python files to apk

Tags: android, python, apk, kivy

i want to convert my python and kivy files into signed and unsigned apk. i work on windows but for compiling using python for android in ubuntu in vm ware. After installing all necessary modules like kivy, python for android and android studio.

when i am compiling it's showing error that sdk not found.
is there any option for generating apk in windows or ubuntu or linux.
i also heard about buildozer and it also works on windows. 
please suggest me something on it i'm new to kivy.
thanks
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmT3P.png)

Comment: Follow @jilgeza's instructions about buildozer, but I'll also note that you must use Linux or OS X for this, not Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using buildozer instead of p4a - the buildozer uses it internally. It can also automatically download specified android sdk for you.

Install it using pip: `sudo pip install buildozer`

Once you have it installed, go to your project directory and type:

```
buildozer init
# edit the buildozer.spec, then
buildozer android_new debug deploy run
```

Find more info [on the github](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer).