# Python+kivy+SQLite: How to use them together

Tags: python, sqlite, kivy

I am new to python, kivy and sqlite. But I have to do this difficult task. :-( Any kind of help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

The task is: to display the data from a `.db` file on the `kivy` screen on android.

I made the database file from http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitepythontutorial/

Here I post the code again.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3 as lite
import sys

con = lite.connect('test.db')

with con:

    cur = con.cursor()    
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Cars(Id INT, Name TEXT, Price INT)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(1,'Audi',52642)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(2,'Mercedes',57127)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(3,'Skoda',9000)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(4,'Volvo',29000)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(5,'Bentley',350000)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(6,'Citroen',21000)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(7,'Hummer',41400)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(8,'Volkswagen',21600)")
```

The database is then saved to `C:\\test.db`.

Then I made a `kivy` screen with a `label` and a `button`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder

import random

root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: 'Hello'  #How to define it?
        font_size: 30
    Button:
        size: root.width/2, 15
        text: 'next random'
        font_size: 30
#        on_release:  #How to define it?
''')

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root_widget

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

I want to have a `random` **car name** from the `db file` shown on the `label`, when the `button` is clicked everytime.

The initial `label` text, which is now the word "Hello", should be replaced by a random car name. So that everytime the programm is run, a car name is shown on the `label`.

But I really dont know how to write the code.

Thank you for your help.

**#Update**

I wrote the code but it does not work.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import mainthread
import sqlite3

import random


class MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout):

    def init(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        @mainthread  # execute within next frame
        def delayed():
            self.load_random_car()
        delayed()

    def load_random_car(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect("C:\\test.db")
        cur = conn.cursor()

        ####Length of db file
        with conn:
            cur = conn.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Cars")
            rows = cur.fetchall()
        LengthSQLFile = len(rows)
        print LengthSQLFile


        CurrentNo = random.randint(0, LengthSQLFile)
        CurrentNo_ForSearch = (CurrentNo ,)
        cur.execute("select * from Cars where rowid = ?" , CurrentNo_ForSearch)

        CurrentAll = cur.fetchone()
        CurrentAll = list(CurrentAll)   # Change it from tuple to list
        print CurrentAll

        Current    = CurrentAll[1]
        self.ids.label.text = Current #"fetch random car data from db and put here"


root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        id: label
        font_size: 30
    Button:
        size: root.width/2, 15
        text: 'next random'
        font_size: 30
        on_release:  root.load_random_car()

''')


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
#        MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout)
        return root_widget

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

**#2 Update:**

The code now is... It shows the error message:  `AttributeError: 'BoxLayout' object has no attribute 'load_random_car'`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import mainthread
import sqlite3

import random

class MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout):

    def init(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        @mainthread  # execute within next frame
        def delayed():
            self.load_random_car()
        delayed()

    def load_random_car(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect("C:\\test.db")
        cur = conn.cursor()

        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Cars ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;")

        currentAll = cur.fetchone()
        currentAll = list(currentAll)   # Change it from tuple to list
        print currentAll

        current    = currentAll[1]
        self.ids.label.text = current #"fetch random car data from db and put here"


root_widget = Builder.load_string('''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        id: label
        font_size: 30
    Button:
        size: root.width/2, 15
        text: 'next random'
        font_size: 30
        on_release:  root.load_random_car()

''')


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
#        MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout)
        return root_widget

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Why do you query search two times? Once you have fetched the data with the first query, just pick a random entry with `random.choice(rows)`. Also, please don't start variable names with capital letters - they are reserved for class names.

Comment: @jligeza Thanks for the hint. I changed it. But it still shows the error message: 'BoxLayout' object has no attribute 'load_random_car'

Comment: @jligeza I pasted the update. Would you please have a look at it? Thanks.

Comment: In the kv string part, you should use `MyBoxLayout`, not plain `BoxLayout`.

Comment: @jligeza That's it! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way would be writing a custom `init` method for the box layout:

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import mainthread

class MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout):

    def init(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        @mainthread  # execute within next frame
        def delayed():
            self.load_random_car()
        delayed()

    def load_random_car(self):
        self.ids.label.text = "fetch random car data from db and put here"
```

This is how the updated widget structure would look like:

```
MyBoxLayout:
    Label:
        id: label
    Button:
        on_release:  root.load_random_car()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But I still have problem with your code. Could you please write a frame code for me, show me how to load the db file, how to fetch the db data, and so on? That would be a great help for me. Thank you.

Comment: @Rita Loading db file and fetching data from it is written pretty clear in the tutorial that you have linked. Which part of the tutorial you don't understand?

Comment: Thank you. I was actually looking for the 'class' statement to load and read the db file. But I couldnot find such statement on the internet.

Comment: @Rita If you want to use classes to describe an sql database structure, then I strongly recommend you [peewee](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/07/17/an-intro-to-peewee-another-python-orm/). It is super simple and efficient. There is also even simpler form of storing your data (no sql, no classes, one of my favs), [tinydb](https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Thank you so much for the information! I must say I love those two tools at first sight! haha... (you dont know how I hate SQLAlchemy.) Thank you again!

Comment: I just found that I cannot install peewee on Qpython. Does it mean I cannt use peewee on android?

Comment: @Rita I have been using peewee on android in a kivy project. QPython doesn't have it installed by default. The easiest way would be using [buildozer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674286/how-to-compile-kivy-and-python-files-to-apk/38676403#38676403) to import it in requirements. Also, please consider marking this answer as accepted if it is sufficient.

Comment: After tried many times without results, I have to give up peewee on Qpython and go back to sqlite. Thank you for help anyway.      I have tried to write the code you gave me into the code I had. But it doesnot work. Would you please have a look at the updated code?