# kivy: How to locate a scroll label in FloatLayout?

Tags: kivy

I have problem to locate a `scroll label` in `FloatLayout`.

The original code is from Alexander Taylor. Link: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Scrollable-Label

I want to have the `scroll label` positioned as the picture shown.

[image]

The position values are:

vtop    = screen height / 10

vbottom = screen height / 20

hleft   = screen width  / 20

hright  = screen width  / 40

I added a FloatLayout into the original code. Here is the code I changed.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

long_text = 'yay moo cow foo bar moo baa ' * 200

Builder.load_string('''
<ScrollableLabel>:
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            size: root.width - root.width/20 - root.width/40, root.height - root.height/10 - root.height/20
            pos: root.width /20, root.height / 20
            #size_hint: (None, None)
#            valign: 'top'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            text_size: self.width - self.width/20 - self.width/40, self.height - self.height/10 - self.height/20
#            text_size: self.width , None
            font_size: 30
            text: root.text
''')

class ScrollableLabel(ScrollView):
    text = StringProperty('')

class ScrollApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScrollableLabel(text=long_text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ScrollApp().run()
```

I have tried with some methods to locate the scroll label, as you may see in the code above, but it does not give me the required results.

I would ask your ideas to make the code correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is your app's main widget is derived from ScrollView, while you only want an interior area to be scrollable. You have your FloatLayout within the ScrollView. I suggest the approach of having a main layout widget and embed the ScrollableLabel into that.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

long_text = 'yay moo cow foo bar moo baa ' * 100

Builder.load_string('''
<MainApp>:
    ScrollableLabel:
        id: scrollable
        pos: self.parent.pos[0]+self.parent.size[0]/20, self.parent.pos[1]+self.parent.size[1]/20
        size_hint: 18.5 / 20.0, 0.85

<ScrollableLabel>:
    Label:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
        text_size: self.width, None
        text: root.text
''')

class MainApp(FloatLayout):
    pass

class ScrollableLabel(ScrollView):
    text = StringProperty('')

class ScrollApp(App):
    def build(self):
        app = MainApp()
        app.ids["scrollable"].text = long_text
        return app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ScrollApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! But may I ask why 'size_hint: 18.5 / 20.0, 0.85'? I dont understand the values here.

Comment: Ah yes, that is from 1 - (1/20) - (1/40), 1 - (1/10) - (1/20) based on the margins you specified.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again. I would like to know if there is any method to place the scrollable label in the FloatLayout? Because I have multi screens in the app. Please see: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025320/pythonkivysqlite-how-to-set-label-initial-value-and-how-to-update-label-text) I have the scrollable label in second screen. If I have a extra MainApp, I dont know how to set label value.

Comment: The way I approach multiple pages is to have a MainLayout (or MainApp widget), then remove a widget "page" by calling remove_widget() on the MainLayout, then add the new page widget by add_widget(). Usually, each page is also derived from a standard layout widget class. (Kivy doesn't seem to have the concept of hiding widgets in the same way as other GUIs.) If you want more detail, plz ask a new question on stackoverflow.